# Как связать switch и enum

Tags: c++, switch, enum

Как использовать switch и enum, необходимо сделать интерфейс как в командной строке. При нажатии >add <Фамилия> добавляется фамилия в базу данных. Как связать switch и enum?

```
/////
enum comands { Add = 1, Remove, List, Relist,Clear, Exit} tst ;
```

Comment: Перечислить `case Add: .. case Remove: ...` и т.д. Не вижу проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum State { ADD, REMOVE, ... };  
State state = ...;  
switch(state)  
{  
    case ADD:  
       ...
       break;   
    case REMOVE:  
       ...   
       break;   
}
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: А чему мы приравниваем переменную типа State?

Comment: @Maxim переменная типа `State` хранит в себе состояние вашей системы. В вашем случае эта переменная называется `tst`. И в зависимости от состояния вам нужно что-либо делать. Этим и занимается конструкция `switch-case`

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос неясен. `enum`ы практически созданы для того, чтобы использоваться в операторе `switch-case`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

enum A { A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 };

void f(A a) {
    switch (a) {
    case A1: cout << "A1" << endl; break;
    case A2: cout << "A2" << endl; break;
    case A3: cout << "A3" << endl; break;
    case A4: cout << "A4" << endl; break;
    case A5: cout << "A5" << endl; break;
    default: cout << "Wrong choice" << endl; break;
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<A> v = { A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 };
    for (auto el: v)
        f(el);
    cout << "shuffle vector..." << endl;
    unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), default_random_engine(seed));
    for (auto el: v)
        f(el);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
D:\Qt\build-enums-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release>.\enums.exe
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
shuffle vector...
A2
A3
A1
A5
A4
```